# Not able to view the drop down options in rails UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below code snippet is a case add form where it  shows the select tag in UI but if it is clicked on its arrow button nothing is viewed, in-browser console it shows all the select options.

```
<div id="addCaseForm" style="display:none">
       <%= form_tag("#{@view.addUrl}", method: "post") do %>
         <div class="row padlef">
             <div class="col-sm-8">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <%= label_tag("Case Title:") %>
                 <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
               <div>
             <div>
         </div>
         <div class="padlef">
          <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-3 f-n32 p7-lr">
                   <%= label_tag("Assign To") %>
                   <%= select_tag 'userId', option_for_select_assignee %>
                   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 f-n32 p7-lr">
                   <%= label_tag("Priority")%>
                   <%= select_tag 'priority', option_for_select_priority %>
                   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-2 f-n32 p7-lr">
                   <%= label_tag("Case Type") %>
                   <%= select_tag 'c_type',  option_for_select_c_type %>
                   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                 </div>
                  <div class="form-group margboth margbot col-md-12 clearfix">
                   <a class="btn btn-primary ftn16 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal cancelAddCase"><i class="fa fa-times-circle "></i> &nbsp; Cancel</a>
                   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit ftn16 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal pull-left" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle "></i> &nbsp; Add</button>
                  </div>
           </div>
         <div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
```

and the helper code is as follows

```
module CaseHelper

def option_for_select_priority
  return([['Urgent','P0'],['P1','P1'],['P2','P2'],['P3','P3'],['P4','P4']])      
end

def option_for_select_assignee
     list = [['','Unassigned']]
     @view.members.sort_by(&:show_name).each do |member|
     list << ["#{member.id}", "#{member.show_name}"]
     end
     return(list)
end

def option_for_select_c_type
  return ([['Issue','issue'],['Change Request','C-R']])
end
end
```

Comment: What does `option_for_select_assignee` return?

Comment: an array of user id and password key value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you're able to view the correct HTML in developer tools, because this...

```
select_tag 'priority', option_for_select_priority
```

returns...

```html
<select id="priority" name="priority">
  [[&quot;Urgent&quot;, &quot;P0&quot;], [&quot;P1&quot;, &quot;P1&quot;], [&quot;P2&quot;, &quot;P2&quot;], [&quot;P3&quot;, &quot;P3&quot;], [&quot;P4&quot;, &quot;P4&quot;]]
</select>
```

So what you really want is to wrap the method `option_for_select_priority` inside the `options_for_select` call. Like this...

```
select_tag 'priority', options_for_select(option_for_select_priority)
```

which returns...

```html
<select id="priority" name="priority">
  <option value="P0">Urgent</option>
  <option value="P1">P1</option>
  <option value="P2">P2</option>
  <option value="P3">P3</option>
  <option value="P4">P4</option>
</select>
```